# PHP decimal to binary conversion without decbin()

Tags: php, binary, decimal

I'm trying to make decimal to binary convertor without using decbin() function. I tried smth like this (which is ok but it needs to be reversed):

```
    $dec=101;
    while ($dec>=1){
    $bin = $dec % 2;
    $dec = round($dec/2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    print "$bin";
    }// output:1010011
```

How could I reverse the output to 1100101? 
Thanks in forward. :)

Comment: Have a look at `strrev`

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work (or I didn't use it properly).I tried smth like this:  
`$binary= binary();
print strrev("$binary");

function binary(){
$dec=101;
while ($dec>=1){
$bin = $dec % 2;
$dec = round($dec/2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
print "$bin";
}
}`

Answer (score 3):

To convert a decimal integer to binary, repeatedly divide it by 2 — using integer division — until it becomes 0. The remainders at each step, which are 0s and 1s, represent the binary number, when strung together in the reverse order in which they were generated.

```
    <?php
function dec2bin_i($decimal_i)
{
 bcscale(0);

 $binary_i = '';
 do
  {
   $binary_i = bcmod($decimal_i,'2') . $binary_i;
   $decimal_i = bcdiv($decimal_i,'2');
  } while (bccomp($decimal_i,'0'));

 return($binary_i);
}
?>
```

Test case

```
<?php
echo dec2bin_i('36893488147419103232'); //2^65
?>
```

Output: A 1 followed by 65 zeros:

100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: this helped me to pass 32 bit system limitation for big int! brilliant!

Comment: This is the best answer, works with huge numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to reverse a string [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

```
$dec=101;
$binStr = '';
while ($dec>=1){
    $bin = $dec % 2;
    $dec = round($dec/2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    $binStr .= $bin;
}
$binStr = strrev($binStr);
echo $binStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     $dec = 101;
     $bos = NULL;
     while ($dec>=1){ $bin = $dec % 2; $dec = round($dec/2, 0, 
     PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); 
    $bos .= $bin;
     }
    echo strrev($bos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 function getBinary($num) {
   $remainder = '';
   while ($num>=1)
   {
    $remainder .= $num % 2;
    $num = floor($num / 2);
   }
 return $remainder;
}   
echo getBinary(10);
```

Comment: Don't you need to prefix on to $remainder, like so: $remainder = ($num % 2) . $remainder;